# Multiple download - CSV file

Tags: python, csv, directory, hyperlink, download

I have a script, below, that can download files from a particular row from **1 only CSV file**. I have no problem with it, it works well and all files are downloaded into my 'Python Project' folder, root.

But I would like to add functions here, First, download not only 1 but multiple (20 or more) CSV files then I don't have to change the name manually here - *open('**name1**.csv')* everytime my script has done the job. Second request, downloads need to be placed in a folder with the same name of the csv file that downloads come from. Hopefully I'm clear enough :)

Then I could have:

- name1.csv -> name1 folder ->  download from name1 csv
- name2.csv -> name2 folder ->  download from name2 csv
- name3.csv -> name3 folder ->  download from name3 csv
- ...

Any help or suggestions will be more than appreciate :) Many thanks!

```
from collections import Counter
import urllib.request
import csv
import os

with open('name1.csv') as csvfile:  #need to add multiple .csv files here.
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    title_counts = Counter()
    
    for row in reader:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(row['link'])
        title = row['title']
        title_counts[title] += 1
        title_filename = f"{title}_{title_counts[title]}{ext}".replace('/', '-') #need to create a folder for each CSV file with the download inside.
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(row['link'], title_filename)
```

Comment: For the directory creation, you can use `os.makedirs`:
`os.makedirs('/tmp/dir1/subdir1', exist_ok=True)`.
Is `title_filename` the name of the file?

Comment: Part with `.replace('/', '-')` looks a bit weird. `Counter` is basically a dict with `int` values, so no `/` possible, `ext` als can't contain slash, so just `title` could possible contain `/`, am I right?

Comment: @NiltonMoura thanks for this. os.makedirs seems the best idea to create these folders I need but it needs to be created automatically with the same name of my CSVs files so I guess your proposal isn't possible? `title_filename` is the name of fhe files from 'link' row of my CSV yes.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I have no problem with `.replace('/', '-')` it just replace / by - when it downloads my files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an outer loop which will iterate over files in specific folder. You can use either [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) which returns list of all entries or [`glob.iglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) with `*.csv` pattern to get only files with `.csv` extension.

Also there are some minor improvements you can make in your code. You're using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in the way that it can be replaced with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or even simple [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict). Also [`urllib.request.urlretrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) is a part of legacy interface which might get deprecated, so you can replace it with combination of [`urllib.request.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) and [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj).

Finally, to create a folder you can use [`os.mkdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) but previously you need to check whether folder already exists using [`os.path.isdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir), it's required to prevent `FileExistsError` exception.

Full code:

```py
from os import mkdir
from os.path import join, splitext, isdir
from glob import iglob
from csv import DictReader
from collections import defaultdict
from urllib.request import urlopen
from shutil import copyfileobj

csv_folder = r"/some/path"
glob_pattern = "*.csv"
for file in iglob(join(csv_folder, glob_pattern)):
    with open(file) as csv_file:
        reader = DictReader(csv_file)
        save_folder, _ = splitext(file)
        if not isdir(save_folder):
            mkdir(save_folder)
        title_counter = defaultdict(int)
        for row in reader:
            url = row["link"]
            title = row["title"]
            title_counter[title] += 1
            _, ext = splitext(url)
            save_filename = join(save_folder, f"{title}_{title_counter[title]}{ext}")
            with urlopen(url) as req, open(save_filename, "wb") as save_file:
                copyfileobj(req, save_file)
```

Comment: Seems adding the argument exist_ok, i.e. `mkdir(save_folder, exist_ok = True)` would remove the need to first check if the folder existed.  This would create it if don't exists, do nothing if it already exists.

Comment: Nice suggestion! My personal preference would be to use [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path): You could save the `os`, `os.path` and `glob` imports.

Comment: @DarrylG, I am not sure that this argument supported in older python versions. Also it's not mentioned in docs of [`os.mkdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) and raises `TypeError: 'exist_ok' is an invalid keyword argument for mkdir()` in my python interpreter (3.9).

Comment: @Timus, I'd personally prefer `pathlib` too but decided to keep code (and imports) closer to original without major changes.

Comment: Huge thanks for your help @OlvinRoght, I just add a print and keep this `.replace('/', '-')` otherwise it stops when a link contain / in the file downloaded. Also thank you everybody for your help and suggestions.

Comment: @bigbox, `f"{title.replace('/', '-')}_{title_counter[title]}{ext}"`

Answer (score 0):

For 1: Just loop over a list containing the names of your desired files.
The list can be retrieved using "os.listdir(path)" which returns a list of the files contained inside your "path" (a folder containing the csv files in your case).